# Find all $x$ such that $\sin(3x)=0.25$ and $5\pi≤\theta≤7\pi$

Tags: trigonometry

Find all $x$ such that $\sin(3x)=0.25$ and $5\pi≤\theta≤7\pi$

I understand how to get to $3x=0.25+2k\pi$ or $3x = \pi-0.25+2k\pi%$ but from there I get a little confused.

I don't understand why you add the $2k\pi$ before you divide by $3$; I also don't understand how to find the numbers in the period after you get $x= 0.005+2k\pi/3$ or $\pi/3-0.005+2k\pi/3$.

Comment: Where does $0.15$ come from?

Answer (score 1):

Pro tip: don't round numbers until the very last step so that you don't lose precision.

So there is nothing wrong with $3x = \sin^{-1} (0.25) + 2k \pi, \pi -  \sin^{-1} (0.25) + 2k \pi$. It seems you understand only one part of this: since $\sin x = \sin(\pi - x)$, we have $3x = \sin^{-1} (0.25), \pi - \sin^{-1} (0.25)$ so that by taking sines, $\sin 3x = 0.25$ in both cases. Then we add on $2k \pi$ to get the general solution, as $\sin x$ is periodic with period $2 \pi$.

Then we divide by $3$ to get $x = \frac{1}{3} \left( \sin^{-1} (0.25) + 2k \pi \right), \frac{1}{3} \left(\pi - \sin^{-1} (0.25) + 2k \pi \right)$. Now to find all solutions in the domain $5 \pi < \theta <  7 \pi$, we know that $2(8) \pi / 3 > 5 \pi$ so that gives one solution. There are other solutions as well: check carefully to find all of them. If you know the shape of the graph, you can deduce there are $2$ solutions for $\sin x = 0.25$ in an interval of $2\pi$, and hence there are $2 \times 3 = 6$ solutions for $\sin 3x = 0.25$.